# Undefined PHP Variable : Undefined variable: pagination in

Tags: php, pagination, notice

I'm using the following code to paginate mysql results using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SuCSIJ5wNU.

Eventhough the code is working perfectly, i get an undefined variable.
":  Undefined variable: pagination in ".

```
<?php

$get_data = $connect -> query("SELECT NULL FROM movies"); // get the table in the database
$row_count = $get_data -> rowCount(); // count rows

// pagination starts
if( isset($_GET['page']) ) {
    $page = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", $_GET['page']);
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

$perPage = 2;
$lastPage = ceil($row_count / $perPage);

if($page < 1) {
    $page = 1;
} else if($page > $lastPage) {
    $page = $lastPage;
}

$limit = "LIMIT ".($page - 1) * $perPage . ", $perPage";

if($lastPage != 1) {

    if($page != 1) {
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $pagination.='<a href="index.php?page='.$prev.'">Previous</a>';
    }

    if($page != $lastPage) {
        $next = $page + 1;
        $pagination.='<a href="index.php?page='.$next.'">Next</a>';
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: [`NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) is a MySQL reserved word. Whether your query is valid or not, you should take that into consideration. Wrap it in backticks `\`` see if that makes makes a difference or not.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear and judging by the code, you are trying to add something to your variable while you have not defined / set it before.

Comment: If by "wrap it" you meant this "SELECT `NULL` FROM movies". It didn't work.

Comment: Yes @JarolinVargas exactly.

Comment: It could only be "part" of the problem. See Marc's answer in conjunction with what I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never defined `$pagination` before you started appending to it (`.=`).

These two are equivalent:

```
$foo .= 'bar';
$foo = $foo . 'bar';
```

To do the concatentation, PHP has to retrieve the value of `$foo`, which hasn't been defined, so you get your warning. Then the concatenation occurs and is stored in `$foo`, so the error doesn't occur again the next time you try it.

Comment: Thanks guys!. I added this $pagination = ''; above and the notice went away.

Answer (score 2):

You simply define the variable to NULL first, before you run it.

```
$pagination = NULL;
```